# .htaccess password and forced login

Tags: .htaccess

I have password protected website with .htaccess. What I want to do now is to force users to login from the index.html page and not from any other which they can do now. ie. I have index.html (the main page) and I have two other pages 1.html and 2. html also protected with .htaccess password. Users can now type http://www.mypage.com/1.html and they will be asked for login data but I would like to force them (before they are asked for login details) to index.html to login. After they are loggedin they can use any link (ie.1.html or 2.html) as they want.

Can this be done by using .htaccess? I would need the whole code. Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you clarify? What do you mean by "force to log in" - isn't that what your authentication does already?

Comment: Belongs to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

With .htaccess you may protect the whole directory with password:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords/file/passwords
Require user myuser
```

you may create passwords file with the following command:

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/passwords/file/passwords myuser
```

You may complete description with good examples in [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking).

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache to protect a directory you can't create a login form on your index.html for it. The login dialog is instead created by the browser.

You can however force people to first go to index.html, by checking the referrer header. If it exists and is different than domain.com/index.html you can redirect to index.html. You'll have to use mod_rewrite for this.