# Secure site folder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am using cakephp for my new project.I want to secure my site with .htaccess.Here is what i want to achieve.

If someone tries to go to my site url which is,for now www.sample.com.User should not get access without giving password or any other security method.How can i achieve this property?? Shall i eloberate this requirement??then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would highly suggest moving to CakePHP 2.x for a new project.

Comment: no need brother....i achieved this with .htaccess and .htpassword...thanks for you sugggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .htaccess you may protect the whole directory with password:

`AuthType Basic

AuthName "Restricted Files"

AuthBasicProvider file

AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords/file/passwords

Require user myuser`

you may create passwords file with the following command:

`htpasswd -c /path/to/passwords/file/passwords myuser`

You may complete description with good examples in Apache docs.

Original Answer:  [.htaccess password and forced login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633710/htaccess-password-and-forced-login)